# Drawing a dynamic button based on the width of a String

Tags: java, image, swing, drawing

So, I have been modding Minecraft for a while, and I saw how it generates its buttons. It takes a very wide image of a button, takes part of the left, takes part of the right side, and puts the two back together to form a smaller image.

I'm sorry, but I can't explain this well in words, so let me just show you with bad Paint.Net skills:

[image: explanation]

However, I cannot get it to work, as it turns out like this:
[image: turnout]

Here is part of my code:

```
public class ComponentToolbarButton extends JComponent implements MouseListener {

    private static final int HEIGHT = 40;

    // ... other methods here

    private BufferedImage getImageBasedOnWidth(Graphics g) {
        BufferedImage finalImage = null;
        BufferedImage rawImage = null;


         // Try/catch block to initialize rawImage

         // Setting font and things here        

        int compWidth = determineComponentWidth(g); // Returns the (should-be) width of the component

        if (compWidth != getWidth()) { 
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(compWidth, HEIGHT)); // Just making sure :)
        }

        finalImage = new BufferedImage(compWidth, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics finalImageGraphics = finalImage.getGraphics();


        // Draw left side:
        finalImageGraphics.drawImage(rawImage, 0, 0, 0, compWidth / 2, 0, 0, compWidth, HEIGHT, null);

        // Draw right side:
        finalImageGraphics.drawImage(rawImage, compWidth / 2, 0, compWidth, HEIGHT, rawImage.getWidth() / 2 - compWidth,
            0, rawImage.getWidth(), rawImage.getHeight(), null);


        return finalImage;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! (I tried to shorten the code as much as I could BTW)

Comment: This isn't much to go on. From the looks of it, you're extending some kind of JComponent, are you changing the background or opacity?

Comment: I am changing the background right after the object is created. Would that have anything to do with it? (And yes, the class is extending JComponent, I'll add that in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after some thinking, I came up with this little hack to demonstrate how I believe it should work :P

```
public class TestMenu extends JComponent {

    protected static final int MAX_HEIGHT = 40;
    protected static final int LEFT_MARGIN = 5;
    protected static final int RIGHT_MARGIN = 5;

    protected static final ImageIcon BACKGROUND = new ImageIcon(TestMenu.class.getResource("/Menu.png"));

    private String text;

    public TestMenu() {

        setOpaque(false);
        text  = "This is some text";
        setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font"));

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

        FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(getFont());
        int width = fm.stringWidth(text) + LEFT_MARGIN + RIGHT_MARGIN;

        Dimension size = new Dimension(width, MAX_HEIGHT);

        return size;

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        int width = getWidth() - 1;
        int height = getHeight() - 1;

        BufferedImage imgLeft = new BufferedImage(LEFT_MARGIN, MAX_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        BufferedImage imgRight = new BufferedImage(RIGHT_MARGIN, MAX_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        BufferedImage imgBody = new BufferedImage(width - LEFT_MARGIN - RIGHT_MARGIN, MAX_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g2d = imgLeft.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(BACKGROUND.getImage(), 0, 0, this);
        g2d.dispose();

        g2d = imgRight.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(BACKGROUND.getImage(), RIGHT_MARGIN - BACKGROUND.getIconWidth(), 0, this);
        g2d.dispose();

        g2d = imgBody.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(BACKGROUND.getImage(), -LEFT_MARGIN, 0, this);
        g2d.dispose();

        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawImage(imgLeft, 0, 0, this);
        g2d.drawImage(imgBody, LEFT_MARGIN, 0, this);
        g2d.drawImage(imgRight, width - RIGHT_MARGIN, 0, this);

        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

        int x = (width - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
        int y = ((height - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();

        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.drawString(text, x, y);


    }

}
```

First, one should never try and build all the image segments in the `paint` method, it will slow down the paint routine and consume to much memory, but for this example, I just wanted to demonstrate the idea.  Use a backing buffer instead (which I think is what you were trying to do anyway).

This will produce this:

[image]

Comment: While on a rant about best practices, you may want to take look at `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(...)`, this will create a `BufferedImage` whose color model is compatible with the systems (in this example, Default) `GraphicsConfiguration`. Basically, what this means, is the resulting image will render faster ;)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that before, I just didn't know what the benefits were. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried it, and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: Glad it worked (considering I put it together first thing in the morning :P)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the coordinates are mixed up in the calls to `drawImage`:

```
boolean Graphics.drawImage(Image img,
       int dstx1, int dsty1, int dstx2, int dsty2,
       int srcx1, int srcy1, int srcx2, int srcy2,
       ImageObserver observer);
```

The width and height dimensions are calculated according to: `(dstx2-dstx1), (dsty2-dsty1)`.

Try this for the left side:

```
finalImageGraphics.drawImage(rawImage, 
        0, 0, compWidth / 2, HEIGHT, 
        0, 0, rawImage.getWidth() / 2, rawImage.getHeight(),
        null);
```

[Drawing an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) is a good tutorial on the subject.

Comment: yes you're right, the coordinate reference is out, I just coudn't figure out how - early moong & not enough caffeine

Comment: This still does not produce the desired result: [image](http://i.imgur.com/HhHWo.png)